# Prove that set of sequence of integers is countable if the sequence have a step of c

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would you prove that the set S of all infinite sequences $a_{1}a_{2}\ldots$ is countable given the condition that $a_{I+1}-a_{1}=c$

For example:

${10, 13, 16, \ldots}$ should be in the set S as $a_{I+1}-a_{1}=3$

Comment: The set of infinite sequences is countable, or the sequence itself? (The former question is what makes sense, but your example implies something else)

Comment: @Soke yes, the example is only to show how is the sequence,

Comment: Are the a_i natural numbers, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers.  They if $a_i$ can be any real sequences with the property then the set of sequences are not countable.

Answer (score 1):

You can define each sequence by the starting number and the difference, which are two integers.  This makes a bijection between the set of sequences and the set of pairs of integers.  Have you seen the proof that the set of pairs of integers is countable?  It is given on this site a number of times and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}|a_i \in \mathbb Z; a_{i+1} - a_i =constant\}$.

Let $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ be defined $f({a_i}) = (a_0,  c)$ where $c = a_{i+1} - a_i$.  [As $a_i$ are integers we know $a_{i+1} - a_i = c\in \mathbb Z$.]

Claim:  $f$ is a bijection.

It's clearly onto.  For any $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, the sequence $\{a_i|a_0 = a; a_{i+1} - a_i = b\} \in S$ is such $f(\{a_i|a_0 = a; a_{i+1} - a_i = b\}) = (a,b)$. So it is onto.

It's clearly one-to-one.  If $f({a_i}) = f({c_i}) = (a,b)$ then $a_0 = c_0 = a$ and, inductively, we can deduce if $a_i = c_i$ then  $a_{i+1} = a_i + b = c_i + b = c_{i+1}$ so $\{a_i\} = \{c_i\}$.

So $f$ if a bijection and so $|S| = |\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z|$.  $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is countable by .... usual reasons.

Comment: You twice wrote "$a_{I+1}- a_1= 3$" when you surely meant "$a_{I+ 1}- a_I= 3$".

Comment: I don't see where I wrote that.

Comment: Um, I think you meant the OP wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

Assign 1-> $a_1$, n-> $a_1+ nc$.

Comment: That shows that a single sequence is countable.  Not the set of all such sequences.  The OP was a bit unclear what s/he was asking.  I assumed it was for the set of all such sequences and the mere fact that the sequences themselves are indexed implies they are countable.